# Incoming vs Outgoing Trusts -- error in book?

Tags: active-directory

I'm reading an exam guide from a well-known publisher at the moment for a Windows 2016 cert and trying to get my head around domain/forest trusts. It seems to me that this section/table in the book is wrong, that the outgoing and incoming words are the wrong way around, but as I don't really grok this area yet I can't be sure.  Can someone confirm pls?

```
Trust Direction     Description

One-way outgoing    The local domain is the trusted domain and the remote domain is the trusting domain. Unidirectional.
One-way incoming    The local domain is the trusting domain and the remote domain is the trusted domain. Unidirectional.
Two-way             Both domains are trusted and trusting. Bidirectional.
```

thanks

Comment: Two answers so far, disagreeing.   Can I get quorum? ;)

Comment: I have the MCSE from Windows 2000. I can't believe this question is still unknown. I did try it once to figure out which way was right. I can't remember what I discovered.

Answer (score 2):

It's backwards. The point of the arrow indicates the trusted domain, and the direction of the arrow relative to the local domain is the incoming/outgoing part.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731404(v=ws.11)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc794933%28v%3dws.10%29

One-way: incoming. A one-way, incoming trust allows authentication requests that are sent by **users** in your domain or forest (the domain or forest where you started the New Trust Wizard) to be routed successfully to **resources** in the other domain or forest.

One-way: outgoing. A one-way, outgoing trust allows authentication requests that are sent by **users** in the other domain (the domain or forest that you are indicating in the New Trust Wizard as the specified domain or forest) to be routed successfully to **resources** in your domain or forest.

[image: Trust]

[image: Direction of Trust]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fine to me. It's from the perspective of exporting or importing credentials.

- outgoing: remote trusts local
- incoming: local trusts remote

Answer (score 0):

I think the book is wrong.

When you look in the "Active Directory Domains and Trusts" console on a domain controller, you see two sections:

```
Domains trusted by this domain (outgoing trusts)
Domains that trust this domain (incoming trusts)
```

So (remote) domains listed under the outgoing section are trusted domains.

And (remote) domains listed under the incoming section are trusting domains.